# Using ASIHTTPRequest with project which is using ARC

Tags: objective-c, facebook, macos, asihttprequest

I've added these files to my project:

```
ASICacheDelegate.h
ASIDataCompressor.h
ASIDataCompressor.m
ASIDataDecompressor.h
ASIDataDecompressor.m
ASIDownloadCache.h
ASIDownloadCache.m
ASIFormDataRequest.h
ASIFormDataRequest.m
ASIHTTPRequest.h
ASIHTTPRequest.m
ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h
ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.h
ASIInputStream.h
ASIInputStream.m
ASINetworkQueue.h
ASINetworkQueue.m
ASIProgressDelegate.h
```

Then in project's build phases added `-fno-objc-arc`, because my project is using ARC and ASIHTTPRequest is written without using it. And when I try to compile my project I get these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest configureProxies] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataCompressor compressBytes:length:error:shouldFinish:] in ASIDataCompressor.o
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataCompressor closeStream] in ASIDataCompressor.o
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataCompressor setupStream] in ASIDataCompressor.o
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataDecompressor uncompressBytes:length:error:] in ASIDataDecompressor.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataDecompressor closeStream] in ASIDataDecompressor.o
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataDecompressor setupStream] in ASIDataDecompressor.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What I am trying to do with ASIHTTPRequest:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=%@", access_token]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addFile:@"/Users/development/Desktop/12t.png" forKey:@"file"];
[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a test."] forKey:@"message"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

---

if I add CoreGraphics, zlib, CFNetwork and SystemConfiguration frameworks (MobileCoreServices is not found in my Xcode) i get these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Gestalt", referenced from:
      -[oglView(checkOSXVersion) checkForOSVersion:] in oglView+checkOSXVersion.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest defaultUserAgentString] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you're using `ASIHttprequest` in Mac OS X project. So you need to follow this instruction.

> **Using ASIHTTPRequest in a Mac OS X project**
>
> To use ASIHTTPRequest in a Mac project, you'll need to link against:
>
> - SystemConfiguration.framework + zlib (as above)
> - CoreServices.framework   CFNetwork is part of the CoreServices framework on Mac OS X. Unless you are writing a console-based
>     application, your application is probably already setup to link with
>     CoreServices, but if not, simply add CoreServices.framework in the
>     same way as described above.

From: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

Answer (score 4):

you need to Add some Libraries that are Required and ASSIHTTP is using these framworks alright.those frameworks are:
-libz.dylib
-systemConfiguration
-MobileCoreServices
-CFNetwork

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't included the libraries that ASI is dependent on. Checkout the [setup instructions](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions), specifically step 2:

```
Link with CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, MobileCoreServices, CoreGraphics and zlib
```

Comment: You need to add libz.dylib and MobileCoreServices. They should definitely both be there. If not libz try libz.1.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Did you included all the dependency ? Because you didn't mention any.
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions
You should include CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, MobileCoreServices, CoreGraphics and zlib as well.

> zlib and MobileCoreServices

By the way you can include libz.x.dylib if you can't find zlib (i don't have zlib myself). And you should have MobileCoreServices.framework since they should be in CoreService framework. If you don't have it then you have no choice that to install it again in order to make ASI works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
- Select the project - targets
- Select Build Phases
- Check if ASIHTTPRequest .m files were added on "Link Binary with Libraries"